Cassandra unit migration from 3.1.1.0 to 4.3.1.0
As part of java upgrade from java 8 to java 11, we are trying to upgrade cassandra version to 4.3.1.0 and datastax driver to 4.17.0. Earlier we were using cassandra unit 3.1.1.0, EmbeddedCassandraServerHelper for testing and cassandra datastax driver 3.11.5. (<spring.version>5.3.36</spring.version>)
As after Cassandra unit upgraded to 4.3.1.0 it is returuning CqlSession we had to upgrade driver version to 4.17.0. I have following doubt in upgrading cassandra:

Can we continue to use Cassandra Unit 4.3.1.0, EmbeddedCassandraServerHelper.startEmbeddedCassandra(50000L) for testcases
Do we need cassandra.conf or yaml file when using EmbeddedCassandraServerHelper
We used to get openConnections,HostCount... from metrics from Session. Not able to get the same from CqlSession ,What is the alternative ?
TypeCodec used to have constructor with 2 arguments, which we could override on implementing them for a customCodec. Now there is no such constructor

